# Does the crossbow from the Dawnguard expansion get your archery level up?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have seen that you can get a crossbow in Dawnguard. Does using this increase your archery skill?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Crossbows fall into the archery category and therefore level up your archery skills.

http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Archery